# Who will be the leader if 6 colonels are in the same squad?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

If I have the Officer Training School upgrade **Lead by Example** and I have squad of 6 colonels, who will be the leader of the squad?

Comment: Generically, if all your troops are the same rank, how is the leader chosen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The highest ranked unit is your squad leader.  If two or more units have the same rank, the foremost-unit on the squad-selection screen is taken to be the leader.

[image: 6 colonels]

With 6 colonels, this is always the third unit.

Comment: hmmm so that's how is it, but say we have an instance that, that lead have a lesser **will** than any of them, does the **will** of those will have their **will** lessened because they have a lesser **willed** leader?

Comment: @ken I'm not sure, ask that as a separate question.

Comment: And prior to buying any increased squad size, it is the second soldier from the left that is chosen - that soldier is always in the same physical location on the screen, regardless of squad size.